# Обновление ядра на Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu

На хостинге установлена ОС Ubuntu 16, но при этом ядро почему то версии 2.6
После скачивания deb пакетов свежей версии ядра и попытке их установить, все валится в ошибках.

Подскажите какой алгоритм обновления ядра должен быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Virtuozzo на сервере? Или LXC?

Comment: виртуалка на OpenVZ

Comment: Ах, как я угадал ;) Но интуитивно понимая, что может быть причиной, совета дать не могу. С OpenVZ знаком лишь в личном плане ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Никакой.

Вы написали, что у вас **OpenVZ**. Откройте ради интереса его описание. В [статье Википедии по OpenVZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVZ), например, можно обнаружить следующую фразу:

> While virtualization technologies like VMware and Xen provide full virtualization and can run multiple operating systems and different kernel versions, OpenVZ uses a single patched Linux kernel and therefore can run only Linux. **All OpenVZ containers share the same architecture and *kernel version*.**

> В то время, как технологии виртуализации вроде VMware и Xen предоставляют полную виртуализацию и могут поддерживать несколько операционных систем и разные версии ядер, OpenVZ использует одно модифицированное ядро Linux, а потому поддерживает только Linux. **Все контейнеры OpenVZ вынуждены использовать одну и ту же архитектуру и версию ядра.**

...просто потому что они используют *одно и то же* ядро. Так работает технология.

Из своего VPS вы ничего не сделаете, переход на более новую версию ядра необходим **на хост-машине**, на которой этот VPS работает.

---

*Вот только на хост-машине переход в настоящее время тоже невозможен!*

Стабильных [ядер OpenVZ](https://openvz.org/Download/kernel) выше версии 2.6 просто нет. Если брать в расчёт и нестабильные, то максимальная версия сейчас 3.10. До поддержки 4.6 ещё очень далеко.

Comment: В силу небольшого количества знаний, даже не подумал в сторону виртуализации, как источник проблемы. Спасибо за разъяснения)